# Quicker way of updating subdocuments

Tags: python, mongodb

My JSON documents (called "i"), have sub documents (called "elements").
I am looping trhough these subdocuments and updating them one at a time. However, to do so (once the value i need is computed), I have mongo scan through all the documents in the database, then through all the subdocuments, and then find the subdocument it needs to update.

I am having major time issues, as I have ~3000 documents and this is taking about 4minutes.
I would like to know if there is a quicker way to do this, without mongo having to scan all the documents but by doing it within the loop.

Here is the code:

```
for i in db.stuff.find():

    for element in i['counts']:

        computed_value = element[a] + element[b]
        db.stuff.update({'id':i['id'], 'counts.timestamp':element['timestamp']}, 
                        {'$set': {'counts.$.total':computed_value}})
```

I am identifying the overall document by "id" and then the subdocument by its timestamp (which is unique to each subdocument). I need to find a quicker way than this. Thank you for your help.

Comment: do you need to update each document N times (for each element)?  Why not update the entire document in python and then do a single db.stuff.update of the whole structure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What indexes do you have on your collection ? This could probably be sped up by creating an index on your embedded documents. You can do this using dot notation -- there's a good explanation and example [here](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/indexes/#indexes-on-embedded-fields).

In your case, you'd do something like

```
db.stuff.ensureIndex( { "i.elements.timestamp" : 1 });
```

This will make your searches through embedded documents run much faster.

Comment: where is he searching through embedded documents?

Answer (score 1):

1. Your update is based on id (and i assume it is diff from  default _id of mongo)
   Put index on your id field
2. You want to set new field for all documents within collection or want to do it only for some matching collection to given criteria?   if only for matching collections, use query operator (with index if possible)
3. dont fetch full document, fetch only those fields which are being used.
4. What is your avg document size? Use explain and mongostat to understand what is actual bottleneck.